# Pixel phone privacy. How to exempt data sharing with google

Tags: google, privacy

Does anybody knows if a pixel phone is able to profile, based on the user's data although a VPN is always active on the phone.
I am also not using any Google apps. I am wondering if the profiling is done on the mobile platform, then sent to Google's profiling analysis servers.

Comment: Android devices don't do profiling, that is done on Google server side. Even if you don't use any Google services they can automatically connect to Google in background (e.g. PlayStore, app scanning, ...) and the Google services can be used by other apps e.g. via PlayServices or directly e.g. displaying a Google map.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to install another ROM that does not have Google Play services such as LineageOS or GrapheneOS.

> I am also not using any Google apps.

It does not matter which Google apps you explicitly use or not, this process is a core part of stock Android.

> VPN is always active on the phone

This cannot be guaranteed unless the phone is rooted as some connections might be made before the VPN is setup.